# What is the solution to release React Native 0.55 app (32 bit)? Considering that from August 1st Google Play Store requires 64-bit version of the app

Tags: android, react-native, 64-bit, upgrade, 32bit-64bit

I kindly need help in my issue related to the strict rule of Google Play requirement of 64-bit version of the app.

The app is in React Native 0.55 and the solution to upgrade it to 0.60 is not possible due to personal deadlines.

I tried to manually update build gradle file as described in the below link. But, the app crashes immediately without giving any error description (I even released it in Google Play Store, of course it keeps crashing).

https://medium.com/@andriidrozdov/reactnative-and-android-64-bit-new-google-play-market-rules-what-to-do-584b067d6f1a

So, in few words, there are two scenarios for the build gradle:

1. If I use below, 32 and 64 bit support (as described in above link) app crashes and accepted by Google Play Store

ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a","x86","x86_64" }

2. If i use below, only 32 bit support, app is working. But, not accepted by Google Play Store

ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86" }

What is your suggestion to this issue?